# Where do I put third-party plugins for Adobe Premiere Pro CS6?

Tags: windows, macos, adobe-premiere

I have a couple of third party `.plugin` files that I want to use with Adobe Premiere Pro CS6. However, double-clicking them doesn't install them, nor does Adobe help give any hints on where to put them.

The Premiere Pro application folder doesn't contain a Plug-Ins directory as I remember it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your operating system, you need to put the files here:

- Windows: `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Common\Plug-Ins\CS6\MediaCore\`
- OS X: `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/Plug-Ins/CS6/MediaCore/`

Copy them there, and don't forget to restart Premiere Pro to have them recognized.

For other versions Creative Cloud, the folder is not `CS6` but `7.0`.

Comment: Why one folder for all programs?

Comment: Because multiple programs may need the same plugin, thinking about Premiere Pro and After Effects, for example.

Comment: is this answer obsolete or in-use still?

Comment: @T.Todua It was valid for CS6, not sure if it still applies to the CC version.

Comment: I just downloaded a "plugin Zip" from adobewebm by fnordware. The root folder is "AdobeWebM-master" -- with sub directories : "ext" "src" "vc" "xcode" -- Is this correct? Just drop the root directory here?

Comment: @ejbytes No, you should download the plugin from the official download page: http://www.fnordware.com/WebM/ — the installer takes care of everything for you and puts a `.bundle` file [in the correct folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfq49.png), not the raw source files.

Comment: It installed, but not working. Rebooted twice.

Comment: @ejbytes Guess it'd be better to [ask] a new question with details or file an issue in the original project.

Comment: I just realized something. Is this ONLY for export and output of webm files? I'm trying to edit a webm file in Premiere Pro CS6. Thanks.

Comment: @ejbytes Yes, that seems to be for exporting only. If you want to edit these in Premiere Pro, I guess you have to convert to some (visually) lossless intermediate format. That'd be the recommended step for better performance while editing, i.e. using an intra-frame only codec like Apple ProRes or DNxHR.

Comment: Just for anyone else that comes across this - it didn't work for me for Premiere Pro CC.  I wound up using the Adobe ExManCmd tool which told me the extension wasn't compatible - https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/creative-cloud/kb/installingextensionsandaddons.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me on latest version that i've just downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me. But it did work when I installed in another folder. That is, Go to Adobe > Adobe Premiere Pro > Plug- ins > Common

Here you will see all those transitions, effects which are seen in 'Effects' while using the program. Paste all the plug-ins there.